# Exploring API Options for Ticketing and Group Purchases: Wizzair and Other Low-Cost Airlines

Tags: api, prices, travel

Do you know if Wizzair or any other low-cost airline provides an API that allows me to access booking information, specifically related to ticketing and group purchases? I am particularly interested in finding out if they offer group bookings for flights and what kind of price benefits I can receive when purchasing tickets for a group or multiple individuals.